# In RSpec, how to test with an instance variable in the initialize method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rspec

I have a class with the following initialized method to cache all users from the database:

```
 class Student < People
    def initialize
      super
      @all_users = Hash[User.pluck(:name, :id)]
    end

    def get_id(name)
       # puts @all_users      => {}
       return @all_users[name]
    end
  end
```

In my test `describe '#get_id'`, I have:

```
 describe '#get_id' do
  let(:student) { Student.new }

  before do  
    allow(User).to receive(:pluck).and_return([['Mike', 10]])
     # puts User.pluck    => [['Mike', 10]]
  end

  it 'should return an id' do
    expect(student.get_id('Mike')).to eq(10)
  end
 end
```

My test fails because @all_users is empty {}. I couldn't figure out what went wrong. I don't want to use `instance_variable_set`. Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: Try putting the `let` after the `before` block. It's stupid, but sometimes it makes a difference, in my experience.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure which version of rspec-mocks you're using, but try the cleaner syntax: `allow(User).to receive(:pluck) { [['Mike', 10]] }`

Comment: I even created a local variable `user1 = [['Mike', 10]]`, `allow(User).to receive(:pluck).and_return(user1)`. I get the same result. =(
I wonder if it has anything to do with the instance variable being in the initialized method.

Comment: That's why I suggested moving the `let` block to after the `before` block. That would ensure the mocking happens before the initialization of the `Student` object. The only other cause I can imagine is something in the `People` class.

Comment: Can you post the `People` class with the initialize method?

Comment: @RafaelSoares it doesn't matter where you put `let`, before or after. It will be called only when it makes a call to `student`. You are confusing it with `let!`.

Comment: A different way to test `get_id` could be to create an actual `User` record and not stub the call to `User.pluck` which i generally prefer for models/services tests. For controllers, stubbing is fine.

Comment: @Jagdeep Singh unfortunately, I’m not. I know the difference between `let` and `let!`. But this weird behavior has happened to me before, for some reason. Granted, it was not the case with this issue, as the test I ran locally showed.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh, how would you create an actual `User` record in the test? 
@DerekHopper, the `People` class's initialized method has 2 unrelated instance variables. 
I ended up creating a method, `def cache_users` to assign `@all_users`. In the test, I call `student.cache_users` after `allow(User).to receive(:pluck).and_return([['Mike', 10]])` Not ideal but the test works.

Comment: Using `FactoryBot`, i would create actual data.

Comment: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot